# Not able to debug in firefox when using $timeout in directive

Tags: angularjs, timeout, angularjs-directive

When I am debugging in firefox and debugger is supposed to enter the directive :

```
dialogApp.directive('myTable', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
$timeout(function(){
 // apply DataTable options, use defaults if none specified by user
        var options = {};
        if (attrs.myTable.length > 0) {
            options = scope.$eval(attrs.myTable);
        } else {
            options = {
                "bStateSave": true,
                "iCookieDuration": 2419200, /* 1 month */
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bDestroy": true
            };
        }

        // Tell the dataTables plugin what columns to use
        // We can either derive them from the dom, or use setup from the controller
        var explicitColumns = [];
       // element.find('th').each(function(index, elem) {
         //   explicitColumns.push($(elem).text());
        //});
        if (explicitColumns.length > 0) {
            options["aoColumns"] = explicitColumns;
        } else if (attrs.aoColumns) {
            options["aoColumns"] = scope.$eval(attrs.aoColumns);
        }

        // aoColumnDefs is dataTables way of providing fine control over column config
        if (attrs.aoColumnDefs) {
            options["aoColumnDefs"] = scope.$eval(attrs.aoColumnDefs);
        }

        if (attrs.fnRowCallback) {
            options["fnRowCallback"] = scope.$eval(attrs.fnRowCallback);
        }

        // apply the plugin
        var dataTable = element.dataTable(options);

       // new FixedColumns( dataTable);

        // watch for any changes to our data, rebuild the DataTable
        scope.$watch(attrs.aaData, function(value) {
            var val = value || null;
            if (val) {
                dataTable.fnClearTable();
                dataTable.fnAddData(scope.$eval(attrs.aaData));
            }
        });

},1000);
    };    
});
```

debugging stops and nothing is rendered further.This is a demo I am working on creating table with dynamic headers(main Idea of this directive has been picked from net itself).Delay using timeout is introduced to allow ng-repeat to  finish  before directive works.
I would really appreciate any sort of assistance in this issue.
Thanks in advance